# How would to write a multiplication of double values in NEON assembly?

Tags: ios, arm, multiplication, neon

The line in question is pretty contained:

```
w00 * ptr[0] + w01 * ptr[stride] + w10 * ptr[1] + w11 * ptr[stride+1]
```

Considering these variables are `double` (but I can downgrade to `float`), I think I can pass one value per register? Would it be more efficient to use the 2x2 matrix W directly?

**EDIT 1:**

This line is inside a loop that is fired hundreds of times per second and has real-time requirements. Instruments says this line takes 60% of the time of the loop.

**EDIT 2:**

This is the loop(s) I'm talking about:

```
for (int x=startingX; x<endingX; ++x)
{
    for (int y=startingY; y<endingY; ++y)
    {
        Matx21d position(x,y);

        // warp patch
        uint8_t *data;
        [self backwardWarpPatchWithWarpingMatrix:warpingMatrix withWarpData:&data withReferenceImage:_initialView withCenter:position];

        // check that the backward patch was successful
        if (!data)
            continue;

        // calculate zero mean (on the patch) sum of squared differences
        int ssd = [self computeZMSSDScoreWithX:x withY:y withCurrentTargetPatch:data];

        if (fabs(ssd) < bestSSD)
        {
            bestPosition = position;
            bestSSD = ssd;
        }
    }
}
```

backwardWarpPatchWithWarpingMatrix:

```
Matx22d warpingMatrixInverse = warpingMatrix.inv();
double wmi0 = warpingMatrixInverse(0,0), wmi1 = warpingMatrixInverse(0,1), wmi2 = warpingMatrixInverse(1,0), wmi3 = warpingMatrixInverse(1,1);

if (isnan(wmi0))
{
    warpingMatrixInverse = Matx22d::eye();
}

// Perform the warp on a larger patch.
int LEVEL_REF = 0, halfPatchSize = PATCH_SIZE/2;
Matx21d centerInLevel = center * (1.0 / (1<<LEVEL_REF));
__block Mat warped(PATCH_SIZE, PATCH_SIZE, CV_8UC1);


dispatch_apply(PATCH_SIZE, dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^(size_t y)
{
    for (int x=0; x<PATCH_SIZE; ++x)
    {
        double pp0 = x - halfPatchSize, pp1 = (double)y - halfPatchSize;
        Matx21d multiplication(wmi0 * pp0 + wmi1 * pp1, wmi2 * pp0 + wmi3 * pp1);
        Matx21d px(multiplication(0) + centerInLevel(0), multiplication(1) + centerInLevel(1));
        double warpedPixel = [self interpolatePointInImage:referenceImage withU:px(0) withV:px(1)];
        warped.at<uchar>(y,x) = (uint8_t)warpedPixel;
    }
});
```

computeReferencePatchScores:

```
int x = (int)u;
int y = (int)v;
float   subpixX = u - x,
        subpixY = v - y,
        oneMinusSubpixX = 1.0 - subpixX,
        oneMinusSubpixY = 1.0 - subpixY;


float   w00 = oneMinusSubpixX * oneMinusSubpixY,
        w01 = oneMinusSubpixX * subpixY,
        w10 = subpixX * oneMinusSubpixY,
        w11 = 1.0f - w00 - w01 - w10;

const int stride = (int)image.step.p[0];
uchar* ptr = image.data + y * stride + x;

return w00 * ptr[0] + w01 * ptr[stride] + w10 * ptr[1] + w11 * ptr[stride+1];
```

Comment: NEON does not support double precision operations in 32-bit ARM

Comment: I will have to use 32bit precision then? I don't really need double precision, it was just to keep it consistent with the rest of the app

Comment: Yes, if you want SIMD on 32-bit ARM, you should use `float`

Comment: Why don't you post the whole loop?

Comment: Posted. It's actually more than one, there are 4 nested loops.

Comment: Are you sure memory bandwidth is not an issue?  You have common factors like `oneMinusSubpixX` and `oneMinusSubpixY`.  The Addition/multiplication can be grouped differently.  Putting `ptr[0]` and `ptr[1]` together and the `stride` values together might result in better memory bandwidth.

Comment: That is a cool suggestion @artlessnoise! Not used to think this way, coming from Ruby :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You typically don't translate a single line of code into assembly. For it to be worth writing in assembly, you have to first assume that you can generate better assembly than the compiler will. Sometimes that's true for vectorized code on NEON, but it's usually because you have special knowledge about a complex loop. You're unlikely to beat the compiler significantly on a single line of code (and will likely lose). Is this line part of a loop that you've profiled and identified as a major bottleneck? Have you already tried Accelerate? Have you analyzed the assembly the compiler is generating and found mistakes that it's making.

---

Trying to do this in ObjC++ is very inefficient. ObjC++ is a glue language for tying together C++ and ObjC; doing both in the same file imposes several performance costs, especially with ARC. Calling an ObjC method inside of a performance-critical inner-loop is very expensive in any case (even if there weren't mixed-in C++). You should never do any kind of function call (least of all an ObjC method dispatch) inside of a tight inner-loop. It's not clear where you're actually calling `computeReferencePatchScores`. The use of GCD here is probably hurting you more than helping (since it prevents the compiler from applying certain vector optimizations).

This is all to say: how a particular line of code is being compiled into assembly is by far the least of your problems in this code. Its structure is fighting clang's optimizer.

Step one is to step back and ask what computation you want to execute, and then read through the [Core Image Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Conceptual/CoreImaging/ci_intro/ci_intro.html) and the [vImage Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Performance/Conceptual/vImage/Introduction/Introduction.html) and verify that it isn't already available. You might also look over [OpenGL ES](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/3DDrawing/Conceptual/OpenGLES_ProgrammingGuide/Introduction/Introduction.html), but OpenGL is often a whole approach to drawing (so it's a bit more of a commitment). It looks like you're already using OpenCV, so make sure it doesn't have available functions to do what you want. (Most of what I see in there looks like stuff built into both OpenCV and vImage.)

The simplest way to improve performance without moving to more powerful frameworks is to move the entire loop into a single C++ function. Then the optimizer can see all the code and apply vector operations on its own. But the next step is to make use of the high-level high-performance frameworks already available.

In any case, you'll want to sit down and carefully work through exactly the calculations you need to perform (I usually do this by hand on paper). Make sure you're not duplicating anything, that you need every calculation you're performing, and that each change you make still generates the same result.

Comment: Yes, I omitted that this line is inside a loop that is fired hundreds of times per second and has real-time requirements. Instruments says this line takes 60% of the time of the loop. Also, I'm pretty convinced about using NEON, after reading this post: http://shervinemami.info/armAssembly.html

Comment: PS: didn't try Accelerate, as it seems overhead of function calls would dwarf the benefit of using it.

Comment: That post is excellent, but I believe you may be misunderstanding it (and Accelerate). You don't put an Accelerate call in a loop. You structure your data to work with the vector processor, and then make a single call to Accelerate to process all of it in SIMD chunks. Similarly, you don't hand-write a single line of NEON usually. You write the entire loop in NEON so that you can optimize the pipeline, which is the important part when working with a vector processor. Using NEON to perform a single operation can be slower than using the CPU. Also, the compiler already uses NEON where appropriate

Comment: The place you should start is to convert your loop into a small number of non-looping Accelerate calls.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification, it is indeed the first time I try to do this. I posted the entire loop, so maybe it will be easier to understand. I should rewrite it to do some prep work and then use Accelerate.

Comment: I switched to `vImage` in the end, but that doesn't make it significantly faster.

Answer (score 1):

This looks to be a 2x2 convolution. If the data set is large, then vImageConvolve_PlanarF with a 3x3 kernel with some zero padding in it will do the job. It tries to skip work on kernel elements that are 0. You would need to convert the data set to single precision.

If the data set is small, then you are probably stuck with scalar code performance.  Inline the function if you can. Perhaps you can figure out how to aggregate a bunch of these together to take advantage of a heavier duty high performance routine.

However, if the weights change from pixel to pixel, then a convolution isn't going to work. You may look instead at the N-dimensional lookup table feature in vImage/Transform.h, if your data set is not huge.

I am a bit skeptical that the time is really spent just in that line. It is best to look at the assembly view in instruments to see where the samples really land.